# How to make public visible my Visual studio marketplace VSIX extension

Tags: visual-studio

I puslished my extension in the VS market place as shown

[image]

But I cannot discover it from inside Visual Studio

[image]

In my first screenshot there is an Availability Non Public column, I guess this might help, but I cannot find a way to configure it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the "..." icon next to the extension's name, then select *Make Public*:

[image]

It may take a little while before the extension appears in the public marketplace.